# how to detect the paypal cookies?

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, paypal

I am working on cakephp 2.3 framework  . While integrating paypal i have found that paypal sometime show message **"we are unable to validate your information. Please try again Return to facilitator account's Test Store At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to facilitator account's Test Store and try another option. "."**

so to avoid this situation i want to remove paypal cookies when user will make payment.

Anybody know how to detect the paypal cookies? i have checked my console for paypal cookies but i haven't found any related cookie with paypal.

Answer (score 2):

For serious security reasons the browser will not send the paypal-cookies to your domain! You can't set any cookies for paypal either. So there must be some other way you are transmitting data to paypal.

Comment: i am not seeting any paypal cookies these are the cookies that were set by paypal . I just want to delete them so that user of my site will never face this issue

Comment: Not seeing them, means no access to them. Therefore not deleting either.